# Find general term of $1+\frac{2!}{3}+\frac{3!}{11}+\frac{4!}{43}+\frac{5!}{171}+....$

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

> Find general term of $1+\frac{2!}{3}+\frac{3!}{11}+\frac{4!}{43}+\frac{5!}{171}+....$

However it has been ask to check convergence but how can i do that before knowing the general term. I can't see any pattern,comment quickly!

Comment: The denominators differ by powers of $2$. The differences are: $2, 8, 32, 128$. Perhaps this helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: For the denominator: $\frac{2^{2n + 1} + 1}{3}$

Comment: How did you get that @cansomehelpmeout

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout $\frac{2^{2n-1}+1}{3}$ (exponent $2n\mathbf{-}1$), I should think. This way, for $n=1$, we have $\frac{2^1+1}{3}=1$, for $n=2$ $\frac{2^3+1}{3}=3$, for $n=3$ $\frac{2^5+1}{3}=\frac{32+1}{3}=11$, for $n=4$ $\frac{2^7+1}{3}=\frac{128+1}{3}=43$, and for $n=5$ $\frac{2^9+1}{3}=\frac{512+1}{3}=171$, which matches the sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the numerator comprises factorials increasing by $1$ in each successive term. For the denominator it requires a bit more observation. The difference between the denominators of successive terms is our cue to guess there's an exponential term involved.

First Guess: $2^{2n+1}+1$ because have a look at the differences, they are differences of $2, 8, 32, \ldots$.

But clearly doing so gives us the denominators as $3, 9, 33,\ldots$ which is thrice of what our actual denominators are so we divide by $3$ to get the desired general $n^{\text{th}}$ term of the sequence.

$$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{3(k+1)!}{2^{2k+1}+1}$$

Comment: The answer is correct but I discourage you to post just the answer without explanation (you may post is as a comment and not an answer) as it does not help the OP with his doubt ;-)

Comment: Anyways, you seem to be a genius at your age. All the best for the future!

Comment: @tatan I've added the explanation. Thanks a bunch for your kind words. Means a lot to me. and All the very best to you too. Cheers :))

Comment: @paras how old are you ?

Comment: Can you figure out a way to prove $2^{n+1}-1>2^n$ for n in $N$(natural numbers)

Comment: @MDesmond If proving that is a follow up to this question, I would suggest you to post it separately. My first though would be to try using induction.

Answer (score 2):

## Hint

> The numerator is easy.
>
> For the denominator, see the succesive differences. If you still can't figure out see [Arithmetico–geometric sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence).

Comment: Well i observe a recurrence relation $y_{n}=a y_{n-1}+b$ where $a$ and $b$ are constant and thus solving it i got the general term. Wikipedia says that arithmetico geometric series form the former type of recurrence but i am unable to see the agp series directly, can you show me that ?( I.e. to write down the series in terms of $ar,(a+d)r^2,(a+2d)r^3...$ and what are a,r d for this question ?)